# Node-oracledb TypeError: oracledb.getConnection is not a function

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

why does not this program work?

I want to connect to foreign oracle database

Before this problem I solved problems with oracledb location and oracle client, two pathes are correct,
Versions are correct

win 7 x64

````
```const oracledb = require('oracledb');

  const mypw = 'DEMO12dscSEd3' 

    function getEmployee(prodid) {
     return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    let connection;

     try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
         user          : "DEMO",
        password      : "*****",  
         connectString : "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=84.252.140.225)                    
     (PORT=49161))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))"
        });
````

```
VS code's Terminal :

*PS C:\NodeProgram\node-oracle> node index
TypeError: oracledb.getConnection is not a function
    *
```

Comment: In the VS Code terminal did you try 'npm install oracledb'?  Did you install Oracle Instant Client and the VS Redistributable https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html ?

Comment: Regarding your code, look at the node-oracledb examples.  You will find it easier to use the async/await style - these automatically return promises.

Comment: I tried "npm install oracledb" and I installed Oracle Client and VS Redistributable